# iCloud How to replace file in iCloud drive using web browser

Tags: icloud

I can't figure out how to replace a file in the iCloud Drive using a web browser (https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/). I'm using iCloud Drive to store my KeePass passwords database. I'm using KeePassium to use passwords from that database on my iPhone. My computer running Linux and I want to replace a database with a new one using browser. If I just drag new database file onto browser, it's uploaded with new name (Passwords 2.kdbx). If I delete old file first and then drag a file onto browser, it works, but KeePassium still uses old file. I can see that iCloud Drive synchronized those changes and I can even see that KeePassium uses something like "Recently deleted / Passwords.kdbx". So I assume that KeePassium tracks that file via some identifier and able to handle renames/deletes which is fine but now I have to always remove and re-add that database file in KeePassium app.

What I need is to just replace file contents via web browser. Is it possible?

Comment: Also posted on https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-replace-file-in-icloud-drive-using-web-browser.2306887/

Comment: It looks like you're following the correct steps to replace a file but KeePass doesn't recognize it.  This looks like an application support issue.  Have you submit a support request directly to KeePass?